# How to call a REST API?

Tags: restful-url

I am having trouble understanding how to call a RESTful service

More specifically, I am trying to call the first API from 
hxxp://teambox.com/api/user

/api/1/users/:id

I don't know how to actually create the URL, how should I use ':id' ?

I tried:

http://teambox.com/api/1/users/?123456
http://teambox.com/api/1/users/?id=123456

but it doesn't work.
Instead of 12345 I am using the integer id I receive from another call, so it's not because of the actual id.

I just don't know how to create the URL with ':id'

Thank you!

Comment: Unless hxxp is a new protocol I don't know about, that might be your problem.

Comment: @jvenema New users aren't allowed to include URLs.

Comment: Lol, thanks jleedev, didn't realize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `http://teambox.com/api/1/users/123456`?

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what went wrong when I tried that, I must had tried that :0

Comment: I am also trying to call /api/1/projects/:project_id/conversations which is defined at the bottom of this page:  hxxp://teambox.com/api/conversation    However, I don't know how to pass the JSON in the GET request. Should I try with /api/1/projects/123456/conversations?type=[JSON] ?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I've never worked with "teambox.com" api, but I believe it should be ../api/1/projects/1234/conversations/?type=thread and ../api/1/projects/1234/conversations/?type=conversation

Comment: The id I am using is the one obtained from http://teambox.com/api/1/projects/    which returns in JSON "id":123456. It seems like I also can't get to work http://teambox.com/api/1/projects/123456 which is supposed to return details on a project